# Import .reg registry files silently in Inno Setup

Tags: installation, registry, inno-setup, pascalscript

I have a need to run few registry files via Inno Setup within the code. I can not use `[Registry]` section as this is a standard installation kit which should pick `.reg` files created and run them.

```pascal
Exec('regedit.exe', 'C:\Support\MyReg.reg', '', SW_HIDE, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode)
```

I want to run this silently so I tried the following.

```pascal
Exec('regedit.exe', 'C:\Support\MyReg.reg /s', '', SW_HIDE, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode)
```

But it does not work. Can anybody tell me what I am missing here?

Comment: Its REGEDIT.EXE not REGISTRY.EXE ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `/s` has to come before the path:

```pascal
Exec('regedit.exe', '/s C:\Support\MyReg.reg', '', SW_HIDE, ewWaitUntilTerminated, Code);
```

---

Though I suggest you better use the command-line registry tool, the [`reg.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/reg):

```pascal
Exec('reg.exe', 'import C:\Support\Banners.reg', '', SW_HIDE, ewWaitUntilTerminated, Code);
```

Comment: Thanks Martin. Any particular reason behind using reg.exe?

Comment: It's a command-line tool, designed to be automated, contrary to the GUI `regedit.exe`. So you can for example redirect its output to a file to capture errors. And it won't hang on you, like the `regedit.exe` did, in case you mess up the arguments :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want execute .reg file in silent on WPI (Windows Post-Installer), add the next command:
{REGEDIT} C:/file.reg

Have a nice day